# Update Git Mirror but keep changes made in mirror

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

We want to migrate our BitBucket repos to GitHub and utilize GitHub Actions. For this we mirror  a BitBucket repo to GitHub and create the GitHub Action. But there will be still codechanges in the BitBucket Repository, so at some point we need to merge these changes in (with commit history).
But as soon as I execute `git push --mirror`, the GitHub Actions folder will be gone from the GitHub Repository, because it's not on the BitBucket side and we mirror from there.

So basically what I want to achieve is, that the changed codebase/branches from BitBucket will be committed to the GitHub Repo, but it should not overwrite the added .github folder containing the pipeline code.

Comment: You'll need to mirror into a local repo, add the GitHub remote, merge/rebase the changes on the GitHub remote into your mirror, then push the mirror into GitHub.

Comment: So the bitbucket repository is mirrored into a local Repository, I then added the GitHub Remote, but I can't just merge/rebase, since git complains that a mirror repository contains no working tree.

Comment: Mirrors are a hack: a solution to a problem that, as far as Git's design goes, doesn't exist. Obviously the problem *does* exist, but Git's design assumes it doesn't. Don't try to use mirrors to *fix* this: it's not possible. Use regular repositories to fix it, with all the pain that brings, and let mirrors just be pure mirrors.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hacky... But something along these lines should work:

```
git mirror https://..... mirror
cd mirror
git worktree add ..\tree
cd ..\tree
git remote add https://..... target
git checkout main
git pull --rebase target/main
git push --mirror target
```